# Does deleting and undeleting the accepted answer remove the acceptance tag?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, deleted-answers, undelete

> Another comment suggests flagging for a mod to delete it, **which makes we wonder if deleting and undeleting the same answer would remove the acceptance tag**. – Oddthinking♦ ([Why does Stack Exchange prevent the author of an accepted answer from deleting her own answer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/why-does-stack-exchange-prevent-the-author-of-an-accepted-answer-from-deleting-h#comment11728_3782))

Well, does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, kind of, but not in the way that thought is hoping it would. The answer technically gets "unaccepted" when it's deleted and the accept mark gets removed from the post. So if you, for example, delete a question, all the answers get deleted and the accepted answer is no longer pinned to the top in that jumble of deleted answers because it's not "accepted" at that time.

If, when undeleted, the original accept vote on the post is still valid (because it was never assigned to a different, non-deleted post) then the accept mark is re-applied to the post at the time of undeletion, as if it had always been accepted.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Would this process (given discussion context) result in the formerly-accepted answer still not being deletable by OP?

Comment: @DVK Yes, because it would still be an accepted answer when undeleted. The only thing that changes that is the asker re-assigning the accept mark to some other post or removing it in its undeleted state.